# Future builder does not updating the passed data when scroll down then back

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a very weird problem.

To clarify first, I have these fields in a document on Firebase

[image]

as you can see in the picture, there is a list in the "likes" field containing two users [blackwolf, sweety]

I used Future builder to show these docs,

```
 snapshot.data!.docs[index]["id"] ==
                                    "2022:12:01:07:05:14"
                                ? print(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["likes"])
                                : print("");
```

Here I just wanted to print "likes" field where 'id' is equal to 2022:12:01:07:05:14.

Here is the result

[image]

Everything works fine.

But when I delete for example 'blackwolf' from "likes" and scroll down on the same page, then scroll up back to the same position it prints this

[image]

[image]

However, the black wolf has been deleted, but it still prints it. I have to update the page or rebuild it in order to print the data correctly

How can I print the correct data without refreshing or rebuilding the page?

Comment: the FutureBuilder makes you get a snapshot only once when you call it, needing to get updates when something changes in your firestore database means that you need to get the snapshots() stream, and to update your VIew based on it with a StreamBuilder

Comment: include the FutureBuilder code, I can help turning it to StreamBuilder

Comment: thank you very much, i replaced Future Builder with Stream Builder and it worked

Comment: oh great, good luck then!